# $T_1$ and $T_2$ time with amplitude damping

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang

Exercise 8.30 of Nielson & Chuang's QCQI says
[image: qcqi8.30]
Equation 7.144, which is mentioned in the text, is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
b^* & 1-a
\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{bmatrix}
(a-a_0)e^{-t/T_1}+a_0 & be^{-t/T_2}\\
b^*e^{-t/T_2} & (a-a_0)e^{-t/T_1}+1-a_0
\end{bmatrix}\tag{7.144}$$
My attempt is as follows.

(1) The first part.

Assume
$$\rho=\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b\\
    b^* & 1-a
\end{bmatrix}$$
After applying amplitude damping
$$\mathcal{E}_{AD}(\rho)=E_0\rho E_0^\dagger+E_1\rho E_1^\dagger$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    0 & \sqrt{1-\gamma}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b\\
    b^* & 1-a
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    0 & \sqrt{1-\gamma}
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \sqrt{\gamma}\\
    0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b\\
    b^* & 1-a
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    \sqrt{\gamma} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix}
    a & \sqrt{1-\gamma}b\\
    \sqrt{1-\gamma}b^* & (1-\gamma)(1-a)
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
    \gamma(1-a) & 0\\
    0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    \gamma-\gamma a+a & \sqrt{1-\gamma}b\\
    \sqrt{1-\gamma}b^* & (1-\gamma)(1-a)
\end{bmatrix}$$
Compare this result with (7.144),
$$\because\sqrt{1-\gamma}b=be^{-t/T_2}$$
$$\therefore\frac{\textrm{ln}(1-\gamma)}{2}=-\frac{t}{T_2}$$
$$T_2=-\frac{2t}{\textrm{ln}(1-\gamma)}$$
In (7.144), when $a=a_0$, the coefficient of $|0\rangle\langle0|$ is also $a_0$. So, in the case of $\mathcal{E}_{AD}(\rho)$
$$\because a_0=\gamma-\gamma a_0+a_0$$
$$\therefore a_0=1$$
$$\because\gamma-\gamma a+a=(a-a_0)e^{-t/T_1}+a_0$$
$$\therefore\frac{\gamma-\gamma a+a-1}{a-1}=\frac{(1-\gamma)(a-1)}{a-1}=1-\gamma=e^{-t/T_1}$$
$$\textrm{ln}(1-\gamma)=-\frac{t}{T_1}$$
$$\therefore T_1=-\frac{t}{\textrm{ln}(1-\gamma)}=\frac{T_2}{2}$$
Which is quite different from the target. **Did I do wrong somewhere?**

(2) The second part. First, apply the phase damping,
$$\mathcal{E}(\rho)=E_0\rho E_0^\dagger+E_1\rho E_1^\dagger$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    0 & \sqrt{1-\gamma'}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b\\
    b^* & 1-a
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    0 & \sqrt{1-\gamma'}
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    0 & \sqrt{\gamma'}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b\\
    b^* & 1-a
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    0 & \sqrt{\gamma'}
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix}
    a & \sqrt{1-\gamma'}b\\
    \sqrt{1-\gamma'}b^* & (1-\gamma')(1-a)
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    0 & \gamma'(1-a)
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    a & \sqrt{1-\gamma'}b\\
    \sqrt{1-\gamma'}b^* & 1-a
\end{bmatrix}$$
Then, amplitude damping
$$\mathcal{E}_{AD}(\mathcal{E}(\rho))=\begin{bmatrix}
    \gamma-\gamma a+a & \sqrt{(1-\gamma)(1-\gamma')}b\\
    \sqrt{(1-\gamma)(1-\gamma')}b^* & (1-\gamma)(1-a)
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$T_2'=-\frac{2t}{\textrm{ln}(1-\gamma)+\textrm{ln}(1-\gamma')}\leq2T_1$$
Which is also far from the target.

Comment: Why do you take $a=a_0$?

Comment: @DaftWullie I try to calculate the value of $a_0$

Comment: My point is that's an assumption you're making. If you set $a_0$ to different values, you'll get different answers. By the way, in your reported version of (7.144), you must have a sign error on one of your diagonal terms, because the trace of the output is not 1.

Comment: I suggest that you take $a_0=1$. This makes physical sense because we know that if you let $t\rightarrow\infty$, then under amplitude damping, $\langle 1|\rho|1\rangle\rightarrow 0=1-a_0$.

Comment: I reached the conclusion of $a_0=1$ as the solution of equation $a_0=\gamma-\gamma a_0+a_0$. As you said, $a_0=1$ is consistent with the intuition. So, I assume that part of the calculation is correct. The following analysis of $T_1$ indeed is based on the assumption of $a_0=1$.

Comment: Looks like it's just a typo. For amplitude damping T2=2T1, see, e.g., http://theory.caltech.edu/~preskill/ph219/chap3_15.pdf (page 32). In general, you should get T2<2T1

Comment: @EvgeniyZh Thanks for this information! Indeed, these nodes agree with my calculation. I found more things relevant: Section 7.2.1 (page 280) of Nielson & Chuang (10th-anniversary edition) says, "$T_1$ ... is usually longer than $T_2$". Maybe this idea leads to the typo.